# I need hlp with urls.py in creating dynamic url, and integrate my feedback model in my existing pg

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-urls

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP4GZ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGUXY.jpg)

I have create my models successfully when i call it on new path its working good but not in existing path

any suggestion please?

tried to create dynamic path such as

existing url path http://127.0.0.1:8000/result?experience=5
want to create a dynamic path where i can display my feedback model in same page

tried path : r'^result/(?P\d+)/$'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.